# Can't use forEach and map to pass an argument to the array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of functions. Then I use forEach loop to pass the argument to these functions. Although when I try to call first function I get undefined in the console instead of 'hey'

Then I try to make a new array from the old one. And try to use map to get the array of functions with the argument passed into each one, but I get an array of three undefined items instead, so I can't even call a function.

```js
const arr = [(arg) => {console.log(arg)}, (arg) => {}, (arg) => {} ];
    arr.forEach(func => func('hey'));
    arr[0]();

    const arr2 = arr.map(func => func('ho'));
    console.log(arr2);
    arr2[0]();
```

What's the matter in both cases?

Comment: You are invoking the functions and they don't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem in the first case, though `arr[0]();` will just print `undefined` because you've passed no argument.

In the second case, the resulting array contains the result of the invocation of each function, each of which returns `undefined`, so there are no functions in `arr2` to invoke.

Your code snippet had the JS in the HTML section, so it didn't run at all.

```js
const arr = [(arg) => { console.log(arg) }, (arg) => {}, (arg) => {}];
arr.forEach(func => func('hey'));
arr[0](); // <-- You're passing no argument here

// This invokes the functions, and builds an array of the functions'
// return values, all of which are `undefined`.
const arr2 = arr.map(func => func('ho'));
console.log(arr2);
arr2[0]();
```

Comment: I've thought I passed the argument in every item of array in forEach loop, so then I can call any of these functions with this argument. 
Corrected the snippet, thanks.

Comment: You do pass the `'hey'` argument to each function in the `forEach` callback, but only the first function actually uses it. The last two make no use of `arg`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nevertheless, a new question appears: why calling forEach on the empty array like this **[].forEach(func => func('hey'));** causes no error, if we have no functions to be invoked ?

Comment: BTW, if you thought that calling them once would permanently bind the argument to the function, it doesn't. Arguments need to be provided every time the function is invoked.

Comment: With `[].forEach(...`, there are no items in the array, so it iterates zero times, so the callback you pass is never invoked. So there's no opportunity for an error to happen.

Comment: All the `.forEach()` method does is iterate the array it was called on, like in a `for` loop, and invoke the callback you provided in that loop. So if the array is empty, the `for` loop iterates zero times.

Comment: Thank you a lot for sparing your time giving a great answers to my questions!)